# VML Background Image is replaced by the color in Outlook App

Tags: html, image, outlook, powerapps, vml

I'm using Powerapps to send an email with text and a background image (a postcard basically). If I open my email on my browser, it works just fine, but if I open it in the Outlook app, I just get a color block with text on it. Can someone help me out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="Text/html"; charset="iso-8859-1">
     <title>Demystifying Email Design</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     </head>
     <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">

    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:500;height:600;">
    <v:fill type="frame" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg" color="#ff0033" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
    <![endif]-->

     <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="70" width="500"; style='background-image:url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg");'>

     <tr width='100px'>
     <td align='right'> <p style='color:white; font-size:11pt; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight:normal; padding-top:52pt; padding-left:208pt; height:62px;width:18px;'> O Eurobic deseja-lhe um Feliz Natal e um Feliz Ano Novo pleno de sucessos. </p> </td> </tr>
     <tr> <td> <p style='color:white; font-size:11pt; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight:normal; padding-top:52pt; padding-left:208pt; height:62px;width:108px;'>Caro Cliente,</p> 
     <p style='color:white; font-size:11pt; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight:normal; padding-top:52pt; padding-left:208pt; height:62px;width:108px;'>Mensagem em inglês.</p>
     <p style='color:white; font-size:11pt; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight:normal; padding-top:52pt; padding-left:208pt; height:62px;width:108px;'>Com os melhores cumprimentos,</p>
     <p style='color:white; font-size:11pt; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight:normal; padding-top:52pt; padding-left:208pt; height:62px;width:108px;'></p></td> </tr>
     <tr> <td Align="right"> <p style='color:white; font-size:11pt; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight:normal; padding-top:52pt; padding-left:208pt; height:62px;width:108px;'>Porque estamos consigo todos os dias, não será diferente nos próximos 365. Queremos continuar a fazer parte do dia-a-dia dos que nos escolhem como parceiros.
    São 10 anos de história, da qual nos orgulhamos e estamos motivados para a continuar a escrever. Com a certeza de que crescermos juntos é a melhor parte desta história.</p> </td> </tr>

    </Table>

    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
    </v:rect>
    <![endif]-->

    </body>

    </html>
```